# LINQ to SQL output an updated value

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following sql statement that I am trying to get into LINQ

```
update MyTable 
set MyValue = Convert(int, MyValue) + 1 
output deleted.MyValue 
where MyKey = 'Number'
```

I've searched high and low, and am unable to find a way to do this SQL statement in LINQ with proper results.

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not updating. How do you update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
var queryMyTable =
    from t in db.MyTable
    where t.MyKey == "Number"
    select t;
foreach (var t in queryMyTable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.MyValue); // equivalent to output deleted.MyValue 
    t.MyValue = Convert.ToDouble((Convert.ToInt32(t.MyValue) + 1));
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: the reason I haven't done this is that it is prone to multiple users updating at the same time and giving an error. The Above SQL statement will run once and allow any user that happens to run concurrently to update the value as well.

example: me and a friend are running code to do an update to the database and then display what it was that we had updated. we would use the above query and then execute at the same time and we should have sequential numbers. whoever submitting first being 1 and second being 2.

Comment: however the above code will show as 1 on the first and then fail the submit changes on the second.